# Is java toString method capable in reading any type object inside content?

Tags: java

Serialization code

```
public class JavaSerialization
{


public static void main(String args[])
{
    serial s = new serial("This is serialization test.");

    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("mytext.txt");

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(s);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class serial implements Serializable
{
private String s;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4616307934661308622L;

public serial(String s)
{
    this.s = s;
    System.out.println("Output of Serilization : "+s);
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return s;
}

}
```

Deserialization code

```
public class JavaDeserialization 
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mytext.txt");

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        serial s = (serial)ois.readObject();

        System.out.println("deserialization  :"+s.toString());
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The serialization is not done by `toString()` so it's not clear what your code has to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

a toString() is a method like any other and it can access anything any other method can access.  Most likely you can access whatever you want provided you can obtain a reference to the object you wish to access.

If you asking if your toString() should work, the best way is to try it but you can do this.

Note: if you leave a buffered output stream un-flushed and un-closed you will lose part of the end, possibly all the data.

I suggest you `close()` a resource when you have finished or use the try-with-resource construct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Serial s = new Serial("This is serialization test.");

    try(ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("mytext.txt")){
        oos.writeObject(s);
    }
}
```